# What are the three parts of a LSN?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, logs

I am curious about what the 3 parts of a Log Sequence Number (LSN) are and how they are generated.

> A log sequence number is an ever-increasing, three-part number that uniquely defines the position of a log record within the transaction log. [Source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2009.02.logging.aspx)

I looked around a bit, and found at least one answer that said I should ["not be concerned with how these are generated"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143119) but I still want to know.

If I run `DBCC FILEHEADER ([AdventureWorks2014], 1)` I get results that show me some important LSN's in my AdventureWorks

> MaxLSN
>
> 45000000001600001
>
> FirstLSN
>
> 44000000084000074
>
> RedoStartLSN
>
> 45000000001600001

They do seem to have 3 distinct parts, what are they, what do they mean, and how are they generated?

Comment: I suggest you read [this](http://rusanu.com/2012/01/17/what-is-an-lsn-log-sequence-number/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Paul Randal in his Pluralsight course "SQL Server: Logging, Recovery, and the Transaction Log" the LSN is composed of three parts:

- 1) VLF sequence number (4 bytes)
- 2) Log block number (4 bytes)
- 3) Log record number (2 bytes)